# Checking for 'nil' does not work

Tags: if-statement, swift, null

I have a property called `typeSpecifier` defined like that

```
internal var typeSpecifier: TypeSpecifier?
```

Sometimes the value is set to `nil`, I need to know it so I check for it, like so

```
println(typeSpecifier)
if typeSpecifier != nil {
     println("not null")
}
```

The problem is it doesn't work, even if `typeSpecifier` is `nil` it will go into the *if block*

#### Output:

> Optional(< null >)
>
> not null

I don't know what it could be, any weird constellation or what?

Comment: It seems like `Optional(<null>)` in the output means that it's actually `NSNull`. Did you try to check `if typespecifier is NSNull`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Optional(<null>)` in the output suggests that it's actually `NSNull`.

You may replace

```
if typeSpecifier != nil
```

with

```
if !typespecifier is NSNull
```

Comment: How would `nil` then look on the console?

Comment: `println(unasignedOptional) // => "nil"`